# Replace compound number with sed

Tags: sed

I need to replace a list of values with texts, but I can't distinguish between numbers 0, 1 and 10, for example:

0 - mamao
1 - banana
2 - apple
10 - strawberry
11 - lemon

sed 's/0/papaya/;s/1/banana/;s/2/apple/;s/10/strawberry/;s/11/lemon/'

```
cat fruits | sed 's/0/papaya/;s/1/banana/;s/2/apple/;s/10/strawberry/;s/11/lemon/'

papaya
banana
apple
bananapapaya
banana1
```

I find problems with replacing values 10 and 11 that should replace strawberry and lemon

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: you can replace larger numbers like `10`, `11` etc first and then replace the smaller ones..

Comment: Please include fruits file.

Comment: You can also use this : `sed 's/^0$/papaya/;s/^1$/banana/;s/^2$/apple/;s/^10$/strawberry/;s/^11$/lemon/'` but Sundeep solution works well too.

Comment: @Corentin Limier, very thanks!!!! Perfect, it worked